# How do I LIMIT the number of rows in a DELETE with DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, limit

I want to add a security on a sensitive table when I delete lines with an SQL request on a DB2 table.

I want to mimic the way MySQL allows you to limit the numbers of rows deleted in an SQL request.

Basically I want to do this with DB2 :

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE info = '1' LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to do that with DB2 ?

Answer (score 10):

```
delete from table where id in (select id from table where info = '1' order by id fetch first 1 rows only)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a weird schema in which I don't have a single identifier for a line.

I identify lines with a primary key composed of 2 columns.

Comment: what about using row_number()  instead? ie where row_number() in ( select row_number( ...

Comment: Konstantinos, it should be 'fetch first 1 rows only'. Word used should be rows and not row even if you are fetching a single row :)

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on your platform.

If you're using DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can just create a select that gets the rows you want, and put that as a subquery for your delete, and DB2 will be able to delete the results of your select. Like so:

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table
    WHERE info = '1'
    ORDER BY your_key_columns
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS A
;
```

If you're on DB2 for z/OS, that syntax doesn't work, unfortunately. But, you can use your primary keys to do basically the same thing (this one also works on LUW):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE (info, key2) IN (
    SELECT info, key2
    FROM table
    WHERE info = 1
    ORDER BY key2
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
);
```

---

Here is an example script that demonstrates how it's used:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEST(
     ID INT
    ,RN INT
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST 
    SELECT 1,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,4 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL

    SELECT 2,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL

    SELECT 3,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL

    SELECT 4,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL

    SELECT 5,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
;

SELECT * FROM SESSION.TEST ORDER BY ID, RN;

-- LUW Version
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SESSION.TEST
    WHERE ID = 1
    ORDER BY RN
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS A
;

--Mainframe version
DELETE FROM SESSION.TEST
WHERE (ID, RN) IN (
    SELECT ID, RN
    FROM SESSION.TEST
    WHERE ID = 1
    ORDER BY RN
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
);

SELECT * FROM SESSION.TEST ORDER BY ID, RN;

DROP TABLE SESSION.TEST;
```

Comment: Why ORDER BY your_key_columns  Would it not be better to remove the ORDER BY and add WITH UR to let DB decide which rows to delete based on convenience of the layout. OP says the limit is a saftey check (to stop it filling the rollback log presumably)

Answer (score 1):

On IBMi DB2:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE RRN(table) in 
(SELECT RRN(table) FROM table WHERE col1 = '1' AND col2 = '2' FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY)
```

Comment: If you are on db2 and on an IBMi can't you just use DFU to get to the one record?

Comment: This is great for my use case where I have a very large number of rows to delete and I want to do it in batches.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary key has multiple values, or you just need multiple values as the condition, this is the query that works:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) IN (
    SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE
    WHERE SOME_COLUMN='THIS'
    AND SOME_OTHER_COLUMN LIKE 'THAT%'
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this query?

```
delete from table D where exists 
 ( select * from ( select * from table M fetch first 10 rows only ) as M
   where M.object_id = D.object_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO XYZ A<BR>
USING (<BR>
SELECT RID_BIT(B) CHAVE<BR>
FROM XYZ B<BR>
FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY) B<BR>
ON RID_BIT(A) = B.CHAVE<BR>
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE info = '1'
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score -1):

Just select a statement, and put the statement inside the delete query:

```
delete from (
select from table WHERE info = '1' order by id fetch first 25000 rows only
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE                                      
FROM Bibl/File                             
WHERE RRN(File) =  (                        
                    SELECT min(RRN(File))   
                    FROM Bibl/File         
                    WHERE Fld1 = 'xx'     
                   )
```

The RRN function is to AS400/iSeries/PowerSystem alone. In other environments there are other functions for the relative record number.

This makes it possible to erase a record of several identical even without UNIQUE key. It can also be used to update with minor changes.

works like the LIMIT but with DELETE and / or UPDATE.

It only works on SQL DB2 in other settings should be changed by RRN function to return the column number

Comment: Stackoverflow understands English only!

Comment: Paresh: ENGLISH: I have put bilingual to reach the greatest number of people. I think what is important is not the language or skin color but the message that helps to solve problems. ESPAÑOL: Lo he puesto bilingüe para que llegue al mayor numero de personas. Creo que lo importante no es el idioma o el color de piel sino el mensaje que ayuda a resolver los problemas