# How can I rewrite a DELETE query so I can limit the rows affected?

Tags: mysql

I am aware that mysql does not allow use of LIMIT with multiple table delete queries. I have looked for a solution online but I am not sure how to adapt them to my need. Here is the query which deletes all content that is not in the content, to keep table along with other conditions.

```
DELETE f
    FROM   field_data_body f
           INNER JOIN node n
                   ON f.entity_id = n.nid
           LEFT JOIN content_to_keep k
                  ON n.nid = k.nid
    WHERE  n.type = 'article'
           AND k.nid IS NULL
```

So what options do I have to add a LIMIT param.

Edit:
Thanks for the help, but most answers are using the `where in` clause. When I use it, I get an error saying "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME"subquery'

Comment: Probably something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1062988.  You need a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the part of the code that selects the rows to be deleted, then place it inside a derived table and join back to the table to be deleted:

```
DELETE f_del
FROM field_data_body AS f_del
   JOIN
      ( SELECT f.PK                            --- the Primary Key of the table
        FROM   field_data_body f
               INNER JOIN node n
                       ON f.entity_id = n.nid
               LEFT JOIN content_to_keep k
                      ON n.nid = k.nid
        WHERE  n.type = 'article'
               AND k.nid IS NULL
        ORDER BY some_column
        LIMIT 100
      ) AS tmp
      ON tmp.PK = f_del.PK ;
```

Comment: Also did this and I get This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' –

Comment: a MySQL-version which doesnt support LIMIT & IN?? This surely is an ancient version, you really should upgrade.

Comment: @Ali: Did you run this as it is? Without any change? What version of MySQL are you using? There is neither `IN` nor `ALL` nor `ANY` in this.

Comment: @ypercube Sorry, I tried again and ran this `DELETE f_del
FROM field_data_body AS f_del
   JOIN
      ( SELECT f.entity_id                       
        FROM   field_data_body f
               INNER JOIN node n
                       ON f.entity_id = n.nid
               LEFT JOIN mbrd_delete_nodes_to_keep k
                      ON n.nid = k.nid
        WHERE  n.type = 'forum'
               AND k.nid IS NULL
        ORDER BY n.created desc
        LIMIT 1
      ) AS tmp
      ON tmp.entity_id = f_del.entity_id ; ` and it worked

Comment: @specializt the version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2`

Comment: @ypercube By the way,is this a resource intensive query? From my bench-marking attemp, executing this on a relatively small database takes close to ~1 sec for `limit 1`.

Comment: Try the `EXPLAIN` on the derived table (what is inside the parenthesis). It depends on the indexes you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE
FROM   field_data_body
WHERE id in (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM   field_data_body f
           INNER JOIN node n
                   ON f.entity_id = n.nid
           LEFT JOIN content_to_keep k
                  ON n.nid = k.nid
    WHERE  n.type = 'article'
           AND k.nid IS NULL)
LIMIT 10; --or whatever you want
```

Comment: I did this and I get This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @Ali: You are surely running some other version and not this query. This cannot give such error.

Comment: Running it as is with replacing id with entity_id returns the follwoing error `You can't specify target table 'field_data_body' for update in FROM clause` Here is the query: 
`DELETE
FROM   field_data_body
WHERE entity_id  in (
    SELECT f.entity_id
    FROM   field_data_body f
           INNER JOIN node n
                   ON f.entity_id = n.nid
           LEFT JOIN mbrd_delete_nodes_to_keep k
                  ON n.nid = k.nid
    WHERE  n.type = 'article'
           AND k.nid IS NULL)
LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to get you in the right direction:

.... WHERE IN (SELECT ... FROM field_data_body WHERE nid IS NULL)

Comment: This is tagged `MySQL`. There is no `TOP` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

[From another question I was able to do the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124418/mysql-subquery-limit)

```
DELETE f 
FROM   field_data_body f 
WHERE  f.entity_id IN (SELECT * 
                   FROM   (SELECT f.entity_id 
                           FROM   field_data_body f 
                                  INNER JOIN node n 
                                          ON f.entity_id = n.nid 
                                  LEFT JOIN mbrd_delete_nodes_to_keep k 
                                         ON n.nid = k.nid 
                           WHERE  n.type = 'forum' 
                                  AND k.nid IS NULL 
                                  AND f.entity_type = 'node' 
                           LIMIT  1) AS t)
```